# Radiative equilibrium of a relativistic black body

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, thermal-radiation

A black body in empty space in the CMB rest frame should (discounting starlight) come to an equilibrium temperature of around 2.7 K.

However, if the body is moving relative to the CMB frame, one side of the sky will appear hotter, and the other side colder, and it is not immediately obvious that these effects will balance out; in fact, it seems like the hot side should win, as absorbing higher-frequency photons from the front side should decelerate the body unless its speed is maintained by some other force, gradually converting its kinetic energy in the CMB rest frame into heat.

To find the equilibrium temperature it seems that I would need to integrate over the surface of a sphere, applying the formula for the relativistic Doppler effect to find out what the apparent temperature of the sky is in every direction at a given velocity. However, I am unsure how to properly account for the relativistic aberration, which causes the view to contract towards the front and expand in the back, which would alter the distribution of radiative power over the surface of the black body even apart from frequency-shifting effects.

What's the right way to approach this?

EDIT: Here's the best I've got so far:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05845v3.pdf gives a formula for the thermal
distribution of the sky in the forward hemisphere (as measured in the rest frame). A model that covers the entire sky would be better, but I figure this will at least serve as a good first-order estimator. (Turns out to be pretty
much the same formula you can get from Wikipedia, but getting it from
an academic paper on interstellar travel makes me feel more confident
that it's actually the correct formula to use.)

So, *half* of the incident radiation looks like this:

$T = T_0 \frac{\sqrt(1 - b^2)}{(1-b~cos(t))}$, where $b = v/c$.

To find the equilibrium temperature, we need to integrate the *power* received over the whole sky; or, in this case, half the sky, 'cause the model is only valid for backwards-moving photons. To do that, we raise the temperature to the 4th power; unit conversion constants don't matter 'cause we'll just be converting this back into a temperature later with a quartic root. The total power from half the sky should then be given by

$P = T_0^4 (1-b^2)^2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (sin(\theta)/(1-b~cos(\theta)))^4 d\theta$

This is a really nasty integral, and but with the help of Wolfram Alpha I get:

$P = T_0^4 \frac{(1-b^2)^2}{6~b^4} (\frac{6 (3 b^2-2)
arctanh(\frac{b+1}{\sqrt(b^2-1)})}{(b^2-1)^{3/2}}-\frac{b (-2 b^4+5 b^2-6)}{1 -b^2}+3\pi)$

But this looks very wrong. It, too, peaks before b = 1. Maybe it
should do that, but that seems *very* counterintuitive to me. This
makes me think that something, somewhere along the way, has gone very
wrong. It also starts out predicting less-than-baseline power when b
gets close to zero, but that's to be expected- it's ignoring the whole
aft hemisphere, so the approximation should only be good for large
values of b.

Soldiering on for now, we can get back to a temperature by taking the
fourth root:

$T = T_0 \frac{\sqrt(1-b^2)}{1.5651~b} (\frac{6 (3 b^2-2)
arctanh(\frac{b+1}{\sqrt(b^2-1)})}{(b^2-1)^{3/2}}-\frac{b (-2 b^4+5 b^2-6)}{1 -b^2}+3\pi)^{1/4}$

And that predictably also looks very wrong. See [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20sqrt(1-b%5E2)%2F(1.5651*b)%20*%20((6%20(3%20b%5E2-2)%20arctanh((b%2B1)%2Fsqrt(b%5E2-1)))%2F(b%5E2-1)%5E(3%2F2)-(b%20(-2%20b%5E4%2B5%20b%5E2-6))%2F(1%20-%20b%5E2)%2B3pi)%5E(1%2F4)%20from%20b%20%3D%200%20to%201).

Now, my first thought was that maybe we can't actually ignore the aft
hemisphere and still get good results; photons coming in mostly from
the side but with a slight forward component will end up coming in
from the front, and those transverse photons might end up providing a
significant fraction of the total power flux at high beta. But *even*
without that, the power should never go *down*; even if they are
concentrated into a smaller viewing cone, you don't start hitting
*fewer* photons by going faster, and the ones you do hit will always
be higher energy.

So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if we visualize a giant blackbody cavity at an equilibrium temperature of, say, 2.7K, then a stationary body inside it will also equilibrate to the same temperature. If that body then moves at some high or even relativistic speed within the cavity, doesn't it have to stay at the same equilibrium temperature? Otherwise, it seems that it will get hotter without limit (if net flux to it is +) or else get colder until it reaches 0K (if net flux is -), and either option seems inconsistent with having a body in a blackbody cavity at some equilibrium temperature.

Comment: @SamuelWeir It doesn't have to get hotter without limit. Radiation carries momentum as well as energy, so whenever the body absorbs energy from a photon, it will also accelerate. Unless *I'm* missing something, the limit is that it ends up at rest wrt the radiation rest frame, having converted all of it's kinetic energy in that frame into heat. So, the net flux should be positive, but not unbounded, unless an external force keeps the body at constant velocity.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the question to incorporate that reasoning.

Comment: The moving body is not in thermodynamic equilibrium with the radiation, so it will not balance out. That this is trivially so can be seen by boosting it really strongly. Now on one side the temperature of the radiation is almost zero and on the other side it may have an x-ray spectrum. For a sufficiently large body (much larger than the wavelength of the lowest cutoff you want to consider), the treatment in the rest system in which the CMB dipole disappears with corpuscular/ray optics should give the correct result. The body (make it a plate) simply sweeps out all the photons/waves ahead.

Comment: @CuriousOne The radiation is not isotropic, but there is still a well-defined total power that the body will absorb, corresponding to an equilibrium temperature at which it will radiate that much power back out. It should, in principle, be no different than calculating the equilibrium temperature of a black body orbiting the sun.
Could you elaborate on the treatment with ray optics? I'm not sure where you're going with that.

Comment: I have no idea why you think that a relativistically moving body is in thermodynamic equilibrium with a radiation environment that is only homogeneous in one particular rest system. The CMB breaks Lorentz invariance. It has to: the source from which it originates is a matter distribution that was in near thermodynamic equilibrium and the CMB contains the information about the rest system of that matter distribution.

Comment: @CuriousOne Do you dispute the fact that the body will have some temperature? The radiation environment around the sun isn't homogenous at all, but you can still define a radiative equilibrium, where incoming power equal outgoing power, and a specific temperature for a black body in that state. All I'm asking is, how do I calculate that temperature when the radiation source is not the sun, but a CMB dipole, parameterized by velocity with respect to the unique CMB rest frame.

Comment: A body around the sun is not in thermal equilibrium, it's not even close. On one side it is exposed to a heat bath of approx. 5800K, on the other side of 2.7K. Thermal equilibrium is not characterized by net power flow but by temperature.

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes. And? I don't see the relevance. It still has a well-defined temperature at radiative equilibrium. I made no claim about thermal or thermodynamic equilibrium- I just want to know how to find the black body temperature at *radiative* equilibrium, which is one necessary condition for thermodynamic equilibrium, but can occur in the absence of thermodynamic equilibrium. Objects in radiative but not thermodynamic equilibrium still have a well-defined temperature.

Comment: The average temperature (which is not the same as an equilibrium temperature) depends on the spectral absorption and emission coefficients and is not "well defined". It is only well defined in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's why I specified "black body"- absorptivity and emissivity of 1. But fine, if thinking in terms of an equivalent temperature bothers you, go ahead and ignore the temperature and just think of it in terms of radiant intensity- how much power do you get from the whole sky? I can do a fourth root to convert to an effective average temperature myself.

Comment: I already told you how to calculate that: swept out radiation in front of the body. You can look at it from the rest system of the CMB. For the emitted radiation you can go into the rest system of the body, where it's an isotropic emitter. Then all you need to correct for is time dilation, since the emitted/absorbed power is a scalar.

Comment: In the formula you quote I assume $b = v/c$ actually?

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, I'll fix that...

Answer (score 4):

An arbitrary speed is tricky, but the ultra relativistic case is easier.

If you look at this [What's the max speed a man-made satellite can travel in space before its circuitry stopped working?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195648/whats-the-max-speed-a-man-made-satellite-can-travel-in-space-before-its-circuit/196171#196171) SE answer, I noted that the *specific intensity * (in W m$^{-2}$ sr$^{-1}$ Hz$^{-1}$ of the CMB radiation is boosted by a factor $z^3$, where $z$ is the usual redshift factor, and if $z \gg 1$, then $z^3 \simeq 8\gamma^3$. The radiation arrives in beamed fashion from a small spot on the sky in the forward direction, with an angular diameter of $\sim 1/z$ and "looks" like a blackbody spectrum with temperature of $z T_0$ (if the CMB has a rest-frame temperature of $T_0=2.7$K).
The solid angle subtended is reduced by a factor $z^2$.

The overall effect of these transformations is that  if in the rest frame the object received a flux
$$f(\nu) = 4\pi B_{\nu}(T_0),$$
where $$B_{\nu}(T_0) = \frac{2h \nu^2}{c^2} \frac{1}{\exp(h\nu/kT_0)-1},$$ 
then in the moving frame it receives
$$f^{\prime}(\nu) = \frac{4\pi}{z^2} B_\nu(zT_0)$$

Integrating over all frequencies we get the usual Stefan's law and find that the total received flux at all frequencies is boosted by a factor of $z^2$. To balance this, the radiated power must also go up by a factor of $z^2$ and so the temperature of the object must increase by a factor of $z^{1/2}$.

I see from your edit that you may be interested in a more general case where you cannot assume that $z \gg 1$. In which case you're on your own!

Comment: Thanks! Not entirely on my own- now I can check that any formula I come up with matches this in the ultrarelativistic limit. That'll definitely help!